# UICollectionView with a dynamic height inside another UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView component as a block inside UIViewController, that will dynamically change its height after constraints was build and after data fetched. Where should i dig out to find a solution.

How to implement [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TFz7.png) component and autoresize it after fetching.

The ParamsTable class with a field of UICollectionView type:

```
class ParamsTable: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {/*...*/}()        

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)

            collectionView.register(ParamCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

            addSubview(collectionView)
            addConstrainsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
            addConstrainsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
        }
        /*...*/
}
```

And the AdPage class with an instance of ParamsTable inside another UIView component:

```
class AdPage: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

/*...*/

let stackView: UIStackView = {
    /*...*/
}()

let paramsTable: ParamsTable = {
    let table = ParamsTable()
    return table
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetch()

    setupViewHierarchy()
}

func setupViewHierarchy() {
    /*...*/

    view.addConstrainsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]", views: stackView)
    view.addConstrainsWithFormat(format: "V:|-16-[v0]|", views: stackView)

    // calculate a 'new' height after fetching
    stackView.addConstrainsWithFormat(format:"V:[v0(\(paramsTable.params.count * 16))]", views: paramsTable)
    stackView.addConstrainsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: paramsTable)
}

extension UIView {

    func addConstrainsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...) {
        var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
        for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            viewsDictionary[key] = view
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO, you don't need a `UICollectionView` for this; a `UIStackView` is a better option (or a `UITableView`, I suppose). Why do you want a collection view, and if you must use one, why doesn't your `ParamsTable` class *extend* `UICollectionView` instead of `UIView`?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I tried to use a `UIStackView` and it seems helped to solve a problem with correct height increasing after fetching data of various capacity